# If $f_n(x)$ are continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$, then which of the following is true?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n(x)$ are continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$, then which of the following is true ?

(a) $f_n(x)$ converges to f(x) uniformly on $[0,1]$

(b) $f_n(x)$ converges to f(x) uniformly on $(0,1)$

(c) f(x) is continuous on $[0,1]$

(d) None of the above.

We say that the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is uniformly convergent with limit $f$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists a natural number N such that for all x in the set and all $n \geq N$ we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

I think that for any given $\epsilon$, this should be true given a large enough N.

So, the answer is option (a). Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: You've listed the definition for a uniformly convergent sequence of functions, but I don't see how you've shown it to apply to the $f_n$ in the problem. Given $\epsilon$, how are you going to find your $N$?

Comment: I am thinking .. this should be true given a large enough N

Comment: Try to find counterexamples for the first three ones. Remember the classical $3\varepsilon$ proof: "if $f_n$ are continuous and $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $f$ must be continuous "

Comment: Also, from a "test-taking perspective," the [Uniform Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) tells you something about (a) and (c).

Comment: For option (a) look into $f_n(x)=x^n$ on [0,1].

Comment: For (b), let 
$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(2x)^n&x\in[0,\frac12]\\
(2x-2)^n&x\in[\frac12,1]
\end{array}\right.\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0&x\in[0,\frac12)\cup(\frac12,1]\\
1&x=\frac12
\end{array}\right.$$